# Appengine Projection Query Costs Not Consistent With Docs

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, projection

I have a test handler with the following:

```
Model.query().get( projection = [Model.name._name] )
```

Appstats shows me the following:

```
(1) 2013-09-29 21:46:38.638 "GET /test" 200 real=2585ms api=0ms overhead=2ms (1 RPC, cost=140, billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:2])
```

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing?csw=1#cost_resource, it should be using 1 read + 1 small for the projected query. Why is it telling me 2 reads (keys_only does use only 1 small)? Also, why is each read a cost of 70 when the docs say 60?

This occurs on both development and production servers.

EDIT: the Model class used is from ndb

Answer (score 0):

What's Model.name._name?  Try using Model.name instead.

Comment: _name is the internal database name used to initialize and store the property. When I use a list of the properties themselves, the query can raise exceptions for odd reasons; at least on my dev server. The query I have now completes with no issues, and I have checked the returned entity to make sure it does contain only the projected prop. I just find it strange that the costs are not consistent with what's shown in the docs.

Comment: I just noticed that setting the 'projection' keyword in the query methods themselves to a list of props is fine, but if you do that when initializing a QueryOptions object, it raises this:

BadArgumentError: projection argument should contain only strings (StringProperty('n', required=True))

I suspect this may be a bug, but I wish someone from the GAE team would provide an explanation.

Comment: You're right, this is odd.  I'm asking because I suspect somehow you're inadvertently issuing two queries, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Where is Nick Johnson when you need him?  =(